# ブランチの切替について

Tags: git, eclipse

ブランチの切替について質問です。

eclipseで操作をしているのですが・・・

ローカルリポジトリでmasterブランチから作業ブランチを作成し、作業ブランチでAファイルを編集中、最新状態へ更新する必要が出てきました。(作業ブランチの変更内容は除いて)

masterブランチに切り替えたのですが
このとき、コミット、ステージングをしていないのに問題なく切り替えることができました。
その代わり、作業ブランチで変更した内容がmasterブランチに反映されていました。

競合が発生しない場合は変更内容が維持されてブランチが切り替わるのでしょうか？
≪理想≫
　作業ブランチ　・・・  AファイルにZを追加中
　↓切替
  masterブランチ・・・ AファイルにはZの内容はない

≪現実≫
　作業ブランチ　・・・  AファイルにZを追加中
　↓切替
  masterブランチ・・・ AファイルにはZの内容がある

現在この現象のせいで、作業ブランチでの編集中の内容を含めてmasterブランチにPUSHされてしまいました・・・。

この場合、`ブランチを切り替える際は必ずコミットをする`という運用にするしか回避する方法は無いのでしょうか？

初歩的な質問となりますが、ご教授お願いします・・・。

Comment: 直近のコミットログがどうなっているのかも念のため確認してみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: CVSを利用指定時は特に何も気にせずリモートへUPしていました。(リリースタイミングが1つしかない開発しかしていなかったので)コミットログなどをもう少し気にかけるよう習慣づけないとダメなんですね・・・

Comment: 意図しないコミットをしてしまった場合でも、push前で変更がローカルに留まっているうちはロールバック(revert)しやすいので、本当にpushして大丈夫かは確認する方が安全ですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 競合が発生しない場合は変更内容が維持されてブランチが切り替わるのでしょうか？

その通りです。

> この場合、ブランチを切り替える際は必ずコミットをするという運用にするしか回避する方法は無いのでしょうか？

git stashで一時的に変更を退避するというのが解決策になるかと思います。

また、今回の事象はブランチ切替時にリポジトリの状態を確認していれば防げた事だと思われますので、git statusで状態を確認する癖をつけるというのが大事な気がします。

Comment: なるほどです・・・。git stashで退避させるのがポイントということですね。
statusに関してはあまり気にしていなかったので、確認する癖をつけて活きたいと思います。ありがとうござます！ただ気になるのですが、statusで確認を⇒スタッシュをした場合、最新に置換して作業・・・といった手順になるイメージであってるでしょうか？

Comment: 「最新に置換して作業」がよくわからないのですが、ブランチ「A」で作業している時に、ブランチ「master」を最新に更新したい。その上で、「A」に更新された「master」の内容を反映したいという事で良いでしょうか？（そして、作業中の内容を更に反映したい）その場合、「git rebase master」、「git stash pop stash@{0}」となりますが、質問の意図とあってますでしょうか？

Comment: 言葉足らずですみません。ブランチ「A」で作業⇒「master」に切替をすることで「A」の編集中内容が「master」にも維持されると思います。そのとき「master」に「A」の編集内容を**反映させたくない**かつ別の編集をPUSHする場合、`git stash`で「A」ブランチの内容を退避後「master」をリモートリポジトリーと同等の状態にする(コマンドがでてこないです。ｽﾐﾏｾﾝ)⇒[master]ブランチに反映すべき編集を実施⇒リモートへpushの手順であっているか？ということを聞きたかったです。（「A」ブランチを最新かつ編集中の内容にするには：⇒「A」ブランチに退避内容を反映⇒「A」ブランチに「master」ブランをマージの手順でしょうか？？）※初歩的かつ知識の無さで混乱させてしまい申し訳ないです

Comment: 操作とコマンドを羅列してみました。あってますかね？？ → 1.ブランチ「A」に変更をしていて、変更を退避（git stash）、2.「master」に切り替え（git checkout master）、3.「master」を最新に更新（git pull）、4.「master」を変更（変更後、git add . git commit -m "hoge"）、5.変更したmasterをpush（git push）、 6.ブランチ「A」に戻る（git checkout brancha）、7.（これが必要かはよくわかりませんが）ブランチ「A」を変更した「master」を追従（git rebase master）、8.退避していた変更を戻す（git stash listで確認して、git stash pop stash@{0}）

Comment: ローカルの適当な場所にリポジトリを作って試してみるのが一番わかるかと思います。↑のコメントの意図がズレていたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: 1の`git stash`は退避であって、けして編集内容は「A」ブランチからは消えないと認識しています。ですので編集内容を成しにする作業が必要ですよね？ということを聞きたいところです。（そもそもその認識があってるのかも不安になってきました・・・）

Comment: stashを行うと変更内容は退避されますので、編集されていたファイルをみると編集した内容は消えたように見えます。（git statusを行うとworking directory cleanと表示されるはずです。）よって、「編集内容をなしにする作業」は不要です。逆に、退避した編集内容を戻す際にgit stash popで戻しています。上記したように、動作させて試さないと理解しにくいと思いますので、ローカルリポジトリで試してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: なるほど認識が異なっていました・・・。コマンドでの操作ではなくeclipseやSourceTreeを利用してスタッシュしていたら、編集内容が消えてくれませんでしたので誤った認識をしていたのかもしれません・・・。再度コマンドに着目して確認します！細かな説明本当に感謝します！